# In Aurelia, how do I populate a modal (with a view and binding) that lives in the main application layout (app) from a view by invoking the router?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

For the purposes of this example, I will use some hypothetical names:

`app` - The master view and viewmodels app.js and app.html of my application

`projects` - A view which is navigated to by using the router in app.

`projects-new` - A view which will populate a modal.

The designer on my team has a bootstrap-modal sitting in `app`.  On `projects` (route: `/projects`), when the user clicks a button, this is what we want:

1. Router navigation should be invoked.  The URL should *now* read: `/projects/new`
2. `projects` loads and binds `projects-new` to the modal in `app`
3. The modal opens.
4. The user either cancels (closes the modal) or fills out the form and clicks "save"
5. The result of the user's action is available in `projects` - so maybe an event object which contains the user's action as well as the model which was bound to `projects-new` (if they saved) is sent from `app` where the modal exists, to `projects` by means of the `aurelia-event-aggregator`.

I started down the route of using the `aurelia-event-aggregator` to communicate between `app` and `projects` but I stopped when I realized I have no idea how the binding is going to work.

I think another acceptable solution would be to create a modal component which provides this functionality, but not placing it in `app`, but stylistically it makes sense to be higher up in the DOM tree.  Is there any way to essentially do this?  Have a component in a view which somehow hooks into the DOM higher up in the tree?  For instance:

```
<html>
  <head><!-- Header stuff here --></head>
  <body>
    <app>
      <stuff></stuff>
      <!-- This is where the view is rendered -->
      <router-view></router-view>

      <!-- This is where the modal component would theoretically attach from projects view-->
      <modal></modal>
    </app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Anj You can always share state b/w components by making them use a shared state object, e.g `AppModalService`. Use DI to inject a singleton of such service to each component. If do this, better think of modal as the modal manager for whole App. However, in your case I would make `modal` a child of `projects` due to their tight relationship, provided styling allow - if not, fix styling :)

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you finally achieved this @Anj.